# Chrome Facebook Connect Window Resize

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am experiencing a weird issue in Google Chrome for Mac OS X (10.6).

I am using the JS Facebook Connect library and `FB.Connect.streamPublish` to share a story on a users profile. If the user is already logged in to Facebook prior to coming to the share page on my site, there's no problem - the window opens as an absolutely positioned div above the rest of my site. If the user is not logged in, though, a pop-up window opens that asks the user to log in.

This works perfectly in Firefox, but when using Chrome, when the Facebook login window opens, it starts gradually resizing itself until it becomes a narrow column - when manually resizing the window, it gradually reverts back to the narrow column. I googled this problem and found that some users are experiencing the same issue, but I could not find a solution.

Does anybody know anything about this?

---

**UPDATE: I filed a bug report at the [Facebook Platform Bugzilla - Bug #9159](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9159)**

Comment: For the las few days, same issue here, Chromium 5 and Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: finally, someone else having the same problem

Comment: Same here too: Chrome under Vista. Tried both the http and https version.

Comment: I'm seeing it FF3.6 on windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

You have to write chrome specific CSS. use class for chrome same like,

```
.chorme #customFieldId{
}
```